# TSQL: Get Letter representation for a Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Are there any built in functions for SQL where I can pass in a number and it returns a Letter that matches the number. Example, I supply a 6 and it returns a "F"

I realize its an incredibly long shot, just don't wanna re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd want to look at the [CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258239%28SQL.80%29.aspx) function:

```
select char(64+6)
```